# Power BI creating a D3 visualization from existing code

Tags: d3.js, powerbi

I am trying to create a custom D3 visualization in Power BI using code from an augmented version of ck corporation's tree visualization, with added search functionality. I have copied the code, added the fields to the visualization without summarizing them, and made the following changes to the code:

1. I replaced any references to height/weight with `pbi.height` and `pbi.weight`
2. I replaced the `d3.json` call with `pbi.dsv`
3. I replaced `var svg = d3.select("#svg-container").append("svg")` with `var svg = d3.select("#chart")`

Here is the entire code.

```
function select2DataCollectName(d) {
    if (d.children)
        d.children.forEach(select2DataCollectName);
    else if (d._children)
        d._children.forEach(select2DataCollectName);
    select2Data.push(d.name);
}

//===============================================
function searchTree(d) {
    if (d.children)
        d.children.forEach(searchTree);
    else if (d._children)
        d._children.forEach(searchTree);
    var searchFieldValue = eval(searchField);
    if (searchFieldValue && searchFieldValue.match(searchText)) {
            // Walk parent chain
            var ancestors = [];
            var parent = d;
            while (typeof(parent) !== "undefined") {
                ancestors.push(parent);
        //console.log(parent);
                parent.class = "found";
                parent = parent.parent;
            }
        //console.log(ancestors);
    }
}

//===============================================
function clearAll(d) {
    d.class = "";
    if (d.children)
        d.children.forEach(clearAll);
    else if (d._children)
        d._children.forEach(clearAll);
}

//===============================================
function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}

//===============================================
function collapseAllNotFound(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        if (d.class !== "found") {
            d._children = d.children;
            d._children.forEach(collapseAllNotFound);
            d.children = null;
    } else 
            d.children.forEach(collapseAllNotFound);
    }
}

//===============================================
function expandAll(d) {
    if (d._children) {
        d.children = d._children;
        d.children.forEach(expandAll);
        d._children = null;
    } else if (d.children)
        d.children.forEach(expandAll);
}

//===============================================
// Toggle children on click.
function toggle(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  clearAll(root);
  update(d);
  $("#searchName").select2("val", "");
}

function dblclick(d) {
    if (d.URL)
        window.location.assign(d.URL);
}
//===============================================
$("#searchName").on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
    clearAll(root);
    expandAll(root);
    update(root);

    searchField = "d.name";
    searchText = e.object.text;
    searchTree(root);
    root.children.forEach(collapseAllNotFound);
    update(root);
})



var margin = {top: 20, right: 60, bottom: 20, left: 60},
    width = pbi.width - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = pbi.height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    branchdepth = 180;
    
    
var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


pbi.dsv(function(error, Name) {
  root = Name;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  select2Data = [];
  select2DataCollectName(root);
  select2DataObject = [];
  select2Data.sort(function(a, b) {
            if (a > b) return 1; // sort
            if (a < b) return -1;
            return 0;
        })
        .filter(function(item, i, ar) {
            return ar.indexOf(item) === i;
        }) // remove duplicate items
        .filter(function(item, i, ar) {
            select2DataObject.push({
                "id": i,
                "text": item
            });
        });
    select2Data.sort(function(a, b) {
            if (a > b) return 1; // sort
            if (a < b) return -1;
            return 0;
        })
        .filter(function(item, i, ar) {
            return ar.indexOf(item) === i;
        }) // remove duplicate items
        .filter(function(item, i, ar) {
            select2DataObject.push({
                "id": i,
                "text": item
            });
        });
  $("#searchName").select2({
        data: select2DataObject,
        containerCssClass: "search"
  });

 function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

//  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", pbi.height);

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * branchdepth; });

  // Update the nodes
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; })
      .filter(function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? true : false; })
      .attr("class","actionable")
      .on("click", toggle)
      .append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d._children ? "Expand" : "Collapse"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.children || d._children ? -1 : 1) * (d.URL ? 20 : 10) ; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .append("tspan")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .filter(function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? true : false; })
      .attr("class","actionable")
      .on("click", toggle)
      .append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d._children ? "Expand" : "Collapse"; });

  nodeEnter.filter(function(d) { return d.URL ? true : false; })
      .append("image")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 8; })
      .attr("y", "-.35em")
      .attr("width", "10")
      .attr("height", "11")
      .attr("xlink:href", "images/glyphicons-51-link.png")
      .style("opacity","0.5")
      .attr("class","actionable")
      .on("click", dblclick)
      .append("title")
      .text("Go to Policy Page");

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
            if (d.class === "found") {
                return "#ff4136"; //red
            } else if (d._children) {
                return "lightsteelblue";
            } else {
                return "#fff";
            }
        })
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
            if (d.class === "found") {
                return "#ff4136"; //red
            }
        })
        .select("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d._children ? "Expand node" : "Collapse node"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1)
      .select("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d._children ? "Expand node" : "Collapse node"; });

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
            if (d.target.class === "found") {
                return "#ff4136";
            }
        });

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}
```

Why is the visualization blank?